# window.open Data URI

Tags: javascript, uri

I have a base64 string and would like to pass it into window.open()

> window.open("data:application/pdf;base64, " + escape(base64String));

My problem is that I don't want to have to specify

> application/pdf

because it can be an image, pdf, excel file and anything else.

How can I do this?

Comment: So how do you expect the receiving window to know what to show? Browsers only sniff the content-type in a very limited set of circumstances. This isn't one of those cases.

Comment: Does this even work? In my case window.open doesn't open any dataUrl, results in blank page (Chrome) or error (IE11).

Comment: window.open doesn't open any dataUrl, results in blank page (Chrome 62 and 63 tested).  Firefox works well.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to know what MIME type to put there, I'm afraid, ideally by getting that information from the same source you're getting the data string from. If you don't include one, [it defaults to `text/plain;charset=US-ASCII`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2397), which probably isn't what you want.